# Easy way of defining multiple variables

Tags: javascript

There are about 35 variables on a page which starts as blank. Each variable is used for a different purpose.

```
var a = '',
    b = '',
    c = '';
```

Is there a shorter way of writing these variables?

Comment: Just remember that being idiomatic should be more important than be fast ;)

Comment: @Deerloper Is entirely right. I find your method to be *much* easier to read than Milind's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var a = b = c = '',
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8pg2mo1/)**

Comment: Can this technique be use to all similar vars? e.g.: `var a = b = c = 10,` OR `var a = b = c = 'Yes',`

Comment: @Becky: yes..absolutely. check the demo. it is alerting the sum of three variable to 30 when `var a = b = c = 10` is used.

Comment: Beware when defining object `var a = b = c = [1,2,3,4]`. All variables are **sharing the same reference**.

Comment: @TaoP.R. thanks. Never seen that before. Does that mean a = 1,2,3 & 4 ?

Comment: You can do this with primitive types but be careful if you assign objects this way !
Look at this example : http://jsfiddle.net/0kbr4nj5/

Comment: @Becky No, it means they all refer to the same object. So modifying `c` will update `a` and `b`.

Comment: Nope. It means defining all variables with [1,2,3,4]. However, they share the same reference so any changes you made on any of them will affect all the rest.

Comment: I don't think that is true. check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/w7cv1hqw/. modifying variable b does not modify variable a and c.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Just because you change the reference of `b` to a new value. You should try modifying the value without replacing it, ie, pushing a new value in, or splice it. You'll see.

Comment: You mean like b.push ??

Comment: -1, This code **does not do the same thing  that the code in the original question does!!!** The code in the question creates 3 local variables, `a`, `b`, and `c` and gives them each a value of `''`. The code in this answer [creates one local variable `a` and two implicit global variables `b` and `c`](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/3nc9dn3p/) and assigns them each a value of `''`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see yourself repeating something, you want to look for a better way of doing it:

In this case, there's something called an Array of variables. Usually, you use arrays with loops to achieve repetitive tasks.

An array is a list of variables that can be accessed by index. It's as if you had a variable named a0, a1, a2, a2, etc... Wouldn't be awesome to be able to go through all the variables without having to type each one explicitly?

This is how arrays and loops work together:

```
var a = new Array(); // declare the array; "a" is the name of your array here
a[0] = ""; // this is how you assign the first index in the array
a[1] = ""; // second, etc

// now stop doing this manually and do the code below

// this is how you loop 30 times assigning each variable in the array to an empty string
for (var i=0; i < 30; i++) {
  a[i] = "";
}

console.log("This is the array: ", a);
```

PS: there are better ways of addressing your question but this one is the most straightforward =)